# Adding string binary numbers

Tags: strings, vb.net

My requirement is to add two binary numbers, say "1001" and "0101" as `binary1` and `binary2`.

```
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim carry As Boolean = False ' Boolean variable to hold the carry if occured
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim binary1 As String = TextBox1.Text 'First binary number
        Dim binary2 As String = TextBox2.Text 'Second binary number
        Dim result As String = "" 'to store the result
        For i As Integer = Len(binary1 ) - 1 To 0 Step -1
            result = bin_add(getbyte(binary1 , i), getbyte(binary1, i)) & result ' calling function
        Next
        If carry = True Then
            result = "1" & result 'if a carry remains add it to the MSB
        End If
        MsgBox(rslt) 'Display the result
    End Sub

    Public Function bin_add(b1 As Boolean, b2 As Boolean) As String'Function which performs the addition of each single bits form the two inputs which is passed from the calling function
        Dim result As Boolean
        If b1 AndAlso b2 = True Then 'both values are 1/true
            If carry = True Then
                result = True
                carry = True
            Else
                result = False
                carry = True
            End If
        ElseIf b1 = False And b2 = False Then 'Both are 0/false
            If carry = True Then
                result = carry
                carry = False
            Else
                result = False
                carry = False
            End If
        Else
            If carry = True Then
                result = False
                carry = True
            Else
                result = True
                carry = False
            End If
        End If
        If result = True Then
            Return "1" 'return 1 for Boolean true
        Else
            Return "0" 'return 0 for Boolean false
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function getbyte(s As String, ByVal place As Integer) As String'Function for getting each individual letters from the input string. i got it from net.
        If place < Len(s) Then
            place = place + 1
            getbyte = Mid(s, place, 1)
        Else
            getbyte = ""
        End If
   End Function
End Class
```

**Notes:**

- It gives good results for me only if the no. of digits in both numbers are the same.

**Question:**

How can I improve the code? Especially, how can I reduce the length of code?

Comment: We don't accept broken code, so I would stick to the first question. But just really quick: prepend the shorter input with enough `0`s so that it has the same length (I'm assuming only positive numbers here)

Comment: I'll refrain from a review, but are you aware that the `And` Keyword [does bitwise addition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx)? Once the binary representation is converted to an integer, this should be trivial.

Comment: while evaluating this i got correct answer. i need to shorten the code, and make it workable with all inputs

Comment: @LOsunG **make it workable with all inputs** -> that's asking others to implement functionality for you, Therefore it is beyond the scope of code review.  **i need to shorten the code** -> This is OK ,because code review is to improve the code.Even though shortening is not always better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For now, let's ignore the fact that there are easier ways to add binary numbers. There are other issues with this code.

---

> ```
> Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
> ```

Why is code that adds binary numbers inheriting from a UI class? There's no need for this. Separate the concerns and create a module for this code instead.

---

`carry` is scoped to the class level. This is a symptom of problems in this code.

> ```
> Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>     Dim binary1 As String = TextBox1.Text 'First binary number
>     Dim binary2 As String = TextBox2.Text 'Second binary number
>     Dim result As String = "" 'to store the result
>     For i As Integer = Len(binary1 ) - 1 To 0 Step -1
>         result = bin_add(getbyte(binary1 , i), getbyte(binary1, i)) & result ' calling function
>     Next
>     If carry = True Then
>         result = "1" & result 'if a carry remains add it to the MSB
>     End If
>     MsgBox(rslt) 'Display the result
> End Sub
> ```

Getting the values from the UI makes sense, but then you loop over `bin_add`, which obviously doesn't actually add anything, or you wouldn't need to loop or have a class variable. All of this logic should happen inside of `bin_add`.

`bin_add` should take in two strings, handle all of the logic, and return a single string representing the output. While I'm at it, methods should have PascalCased verb-noun names. This method should be called `AddBinary` and I will refer to it as such for the rest of the review.

As I said earlier, I wouldn't expect a Function that adds binary numbers to take in Boolean values. I would rather it actually take in a byte and overload the method to handle string representation, but I'm lazy and you don't seem to need all that.

Putting it all together, the signature line

> ```
> Public Function bin_add(b1 As Boolean, b2 As Boolean) As String
> ```

Should look like this.

```
Public Function AddBinary(value1 as String, value2 as String) As String
```

Implementing this change will be left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

Once the user input is validated to be ones or zeros in the textboxes the conversion / addition is simple.  Using the OP's input parameters:

```
    'verify user input as a binary digit 
    For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
        If Not (c = "0"c OrElse c = "1"c) Then
            Stop 'not a binary digit - error handling needed
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    For Each c As Char In TextBox2.Text
        If Not (c = "0"c OrElse c = "1"c) Then
            Stop 'not a binary digit - error handling needed
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
    Dim num1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text, 2)
    Dim num2 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text, 2)

    Dim answer As Integer = num1 + num2
```

One of the overloads to Convert.ToInt32 accepts a base(radix) to be used in the conversion.

Comment: You might want to add, which (by the way absolutely cool) feature of .net you're exploiting, including a link to documentation ;) Additionally you could make the code easier to understand by extracting `TextBox1.Text` and `TextBox2.Text` to local variables, but that's yours to decide